# Pyp3 gives ModuleNotFoundError even if packaged is install

Tags: python

So I'm trying to figure out if I can speed up my code. For that purpose I installed pyp3. But when I try to run the python file using pyp3 I get error in the first line itself  ModuleNotFoundError, But when I use simple python my code works smoothly. Is it due to python version difference ? I'm new to pyp3. Any suggestion/help would be appreciated. Thankyou

```
pypy3 main_feature_extraction.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_feature_extraction.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

Comment: Please clarify under what conditions does your script work.  If dotenv isn't installed in your python3 setup, then pyp3 won't find it.

Comment: It is installed. As I said it runs smoothly when I simply use python main_feature_extraction.py. Moreover, I still tried to install the dotenv package but it says requirement already satisfied.

Comment: How did you install dotenv?

Comment: pip install python-dotenv

Comment: ```pip install <module>``` installs the module to your regular python library site-packages directory.   It doesn't touch your pyp3's site-packages directory.   Afaik, you use ```pip3 install python-dotenv``` to install that.

Comment: pip3 install python-dotenv
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.14.0)

Comment: pypy3 -m pip install python-dotenv. This worked